# splitting two files based on a different pattern each time in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have below scenario, where I have to split two files based on two different patterns..

Pls. consider I have below text file:

```
$cat file1
```

```
====S
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
====G
qrst
uvwX
yzab
```

for this I have a script like `awk '/====/{x="S"++i;next}{print > x;}'` - which is splitting two files like S,S1.

There are few exception files which don't have first pattern ====S

It looks like

```
====G
qrst
uvwX
yzab
```

If I run the above script for this kind of file, I get the file name S , which is adding these records to the first pattern ====S. But,  here  I want the file name S1. That means if I have only ====G in the file, I need these values to be put in S1 file.

How can I achieve this? Request your time and provide any solution for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

just use map to remember the pattern.

```
  cat t.log 
    ====S
    abcd
    efgh
    ijkl
    mnop
    ====G
    qrst
    uvwX
    yzab

    cat t1.log 
    ====G
    qrst
    uvwX
    yzab

    awk '/====/{cur=$0; if(!p[$cur]){p[$cur]="S"++i}; file=p[$cur];next}{print >file;}' t.log t1.log
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you give me more details on this?? Pls explain in detail the awk command...I'm a beginner..

Comment: `awk` is an entire programming language.  There are plenty of docs out there to learn about it, but maybe @sigmalha will explain his code to you.